# find installed programs after reinstall windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have 2 disks in my computer. 1 SSD and 1 HDD. I had installed windows on the SSD and all my other programs on the HDD.

Recently I reinstalled windows 10 on the SSD but kept the content and programs I installed on the HDD.

The issue i'm facing now is that all those programs are now "invisible" to windows. I can still start them, but the start/search menu can't find them.

Is there any way to "re-index" (or something like that) windows so it can find those programs?

Comment: No; You will need to reinstall them

Answer (score 1):

Though these programs files are kept on HDD, but because we reinstall the windows 10 on the SSD, after reinstalling the system, the start menu is the information of the new operating system.

Some programs may be used directly, we only need to create corresponding shortcuts. However, some programs may not be directly usable, we must reinstall these programs, then we can find these programs and use them in start/search menu on the new Windows 10.